# How to post javascript boolean result back to server

Tags: javascript, html

On the html page of a custom built shopping cart, I need to be able to send a post back to our server to tell it whether or not cookies are enabled.

I have the appropriate javascript on the page to detect cookies enabled/disabled (via navigator.cookieEnabled), which does nothing if it detects cookies enabled, and posts a message if they’re not enabled. I need to go beyond just posting a message.

I don’t want the user to be able to click the purchase button, the html for which (along with the cart itself, and all the items the cart contains) is generated by our database software on our server (using associated cookie ID to generate the cart on the website).

I can not figure out how to get the boolean value (enabled/true or disabled/false) out of the javascript and post that info (true or false) back to our server, where I can detect an incoming connection from the website.

Very much a novice where it comes to JS, so go easy on me!

Thanks in advance for any input you can give me, or point me in a direction…

Here is followup based on answers received:

```
On the cart page (which is displayed when user hits a “Buy This” button elsewhere on the site, to purchase something) is this JS:

<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
    var xyz = "";
    xyz = "Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xyz;
    if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
        xyz = "";
    } else { 
        xyz = "Cookies seem to be disabled in your browser.";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xyz;
</script>
```

So, there is a true/false value generated within the JS. Then, to build the cart, as the html page loads, I send a call to our web server, via this (which is part of the html code on the same page as the above JS):

"4DHTML vCart" 
(this is enclosed within comment tags, although it is not a comment. I couldn't put it within comment tags in this edit, because it got ignored). It is picked up by a method called “On Web Connection” in our web server software, which is written in 4th Dimension (it’s basically 4D code embedded in the html, and the comment tags are part of the protocol).

The 4D code then builds the cart and sends it (the cart page) back to the website as an html file.

So… when the call is picked up by the OWC method, I can detect incoming vars from the html cart page, which come in in arrays, and can parse those values. The problem is, the boolean values I want are in the JS and I don’t know how to represent them outside of the JS.

Thank you for your time and consideration on this.

Comment: Provide code. Basically sending to server even `1`/`0` as true/false will work.

Comment: Kindly share your code, if you are sending smthing back to server, most probably you are using AJAX, simply use true, false as variables values while submitting date in AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do an AJAX post back to the server. Try something like this:

```
<script>
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if(request.status === 200) { 
          //PERFORM ANY ADDITIONAL ACTIONS AFTER A SUCCESSFUL POST HERE...
        } else {
          alert('An error occurred. Please try again.');
        }
      }
    }

    var xyz = "";
    xyz = "Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xyz;
    if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
        xyz = "";
        request.open('POST', 'http://yourpostbackurl.com/enabled');
        request.send();
    } else { 
        request.open('POST', 'http://yourpostbackurl.com/disabled');
        request.send();
        xyz = "Cookies seem to be disabled in your browser.";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xyz;
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, Matt. I think that's going to work. In the incoming url, I see "disabled" or "enabled" depending on cookie enabled state, which is exactly what I want. However, it throws the error alert every time. I would also like to understand how this works. Can you give me a brief explanation?